# How to merge multiple spreadsheet content having the list of keys to them?

Tags: google-sheets

**Input**: column of Google keys for spreadsheet that contains tables with some data, eg:

```
date | refNum | Name | Description
```

**Require**: a sheet that will contain a merged table with data from spreadsheets referenced by keys.

**Actual Results:**

for two cells that contains two spreadsheet keys

```
C21:C22
```

I tried the next formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( {importrange(C21, "A13:C23" ) ; importrange(C22, "A13:C23" )})
```

and it is working well, but what I need, is something more autamatic, to not be in situation to modify every time the formula when I add a new spreadsheet key.

Does anybody know HOW TO get it?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use CONCATENATE or the ampersand operator to create the formula for you, but the result will be a text. Then copy, paste as value and edit the result to have a working formula.

You could automate this with Google Apps Script.

**References**
[CONCATENATE - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)
[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)